# Pandas: Refer to column name, case insensitive

Tags: python, pandas, case-insensitive

Using `Pandas DataFrame`, let's say I have a bunch of columns in a *csv* file, and I want to be able to access any one of them via case insensitive name.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv, delimiter=",")

df2 = df["Size"]
```

The actual column name is `"Size"`. What can I do so that `df2 = df["sIZE"]` can also be accepted?

Comment: have you tried changing the column names using df.columns to all lower or upper case? You can do that using "df.columns = map(str.lower, df.columns)". Maybe that can solve your issue.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you can just call [`str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html#pandas.Series.str.lower) on the `columns`:

```
In [12]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Size','COLOUR','caTegory'])
df.columns

Out[12]:
Index(['Size', 'COLOUR', 'caTegory'], dtype='object')

In [14]:
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
df.columns

Out[14]:
Index(['size', 'colour', 'category'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: It appears that casefolding is not supported.

Answer (score 18):

Have you tried changing the column names using df.columns to all lower or upper case? You can do that using

`df.columns = map(str.lower, df.columns)`

Maybe that can solve your issue.

Answer (score 10):

Why not normalize the column names in `df`?

```
df.columns = [c.lower() for c in df.columns]
```